# Calculate difference between 2 specified rows of cumulative data

Tags: sql, mariadb, aggregate-functions, where-clause

Database Version 10.5.6-MariaDB

Operating System Linux XX 5.9.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue, 10 Nov 2020 22:44:11 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have a table that is automatically populated with cumulative data,
What I would like is some SQL to show the difference between 2 given rows of data.

This is my current result set

```
+------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| l_id | start_date | last_date | num_days | num_hits | num_sales | last_seen_on |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
|    1 |          3 |        13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5 |
|    3 |          3 |        13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5 |
|    4 |          3 |        13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5 |
|    5 |          3 |        13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5 |
|    6 |          3 |        13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5 |
|    7 |         13 |        13 |        0 |        0 |         0 |            5 |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Note that product l_id = 2 is missing as it does not have a record for l_date = 13.

## Q1

Is the query shown below the correct way to get the data, or is there a better way?

## Q2

Is it possible to get the start date (currently hardcoded as ed.data_date >= 3) and the end date (currently hardcoded as ld.data_date <= 15) passed from a WHERE clause?

## Q3

Is it possible to get the data for product id = 2 in the result set?

Many thanks

## Table Definition

```
  CREATE TABLE
  trc_warehouse_product
  (
      data_date INT DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    , product_id INT NOT NULL
    , cumulative_product_hits INT
    , cumulative_product_sales INT
    , date_last_seen INT
    , UNIQUE INDEX date_product (data_date, product_id)
  )
```

## Sample Data For Testing Only

```
  INSERT INTO
  trc_warehouse_product
    (data_date, product_id, cumulative_product_hits, cumulative_product_sales, date_last_seen)
  VALUES
      (1,1,1,1,1)
    , (1,2,1,1,1)
    , (1,3,1,1,1)
    , (1,4,1,1,1)
    , (1,5,1,1,1)
    , (1,6,1,1,1)

    , (3,1,2,2,2)
    , (3,2,2,2,2)
    , (3,3,2,2,2)
    , (3,4,2,2,2)
    , (3,5,2,2,2)
    , (3,6,2,2,2)

    , (5,1,3,3,3)
    , (5,2,3,3,3)
    , (5,3,3,3,3)
    , (5,4,3,3,3)
    , (5,5,3,3,3)
    , (5,6,3,3,3)
    , (5,7,3,3,3)     -- New product added

    , (8,1,4,4,4)
    , (8,2,4,4,4)
    , (8,3,4,4,4)
    , (8,4,4,4,4)
    , (8,5,4,4,4)
    , (8,6,4,4,4)
    , (8,7,4,4,4)

    , (13,1,5,5,5)
--    , (13,2,5,5,5)    Product removed
    , (13,3,5,5,5)
    , (13,4,5,5,5)
    , (13,5,5,5,5)
    , (13,6,5,5,5)
    , (13,7,5,5,5)
```

## Query

```
 SELECT
    t_last_date.l_id
  , IF(ISNULL(t_first_date.f_date), t_last_date.l_date, t_first_date.f_date)          AS start_date
  , t_last_date.l_date                                                                AS last_date
  , IF(ISNULL(t_first_date.f_date),  0, (t_last_date.l_date - t_first_date.f_date))   AS num_days
  , IF(ISNULL(t_first_date.f_hits),  0, (t_last_date.l_hits - t_first_date.f_hits))   AS num_hits
  , IF(ISNULL(t_first_date.f_sales), 0, (t_last_date.l_sales - t_first_date.f_sales)) AS num_sales
  , t_last_date.l_last_seen                                                            AS last_seen_on
--  , t_last_date.*   FOR DEBUGGING
--  , t_first_date.*   FOR DEBUGGING
FROM
(
  WITH latest_date AS
  (
    SELECT
        ld.data_date
    FROM
        trc_warehouse_product AS ld
    WHERE
        ld.data_date <= 15
    ORDER BY
        ld.data_date DESC
    LIMIT
        1
  )
  SELECT
      l.data_date                 AS l_date
    , l.product_id                AS l_id
    , l.cumulative_product_hits   AS l_hits
    , l.cumulative_product_sales  AS l_sales
    , l.date_last_seen            AS l_last_seen
  FROM
      trc_warehouse_product AS l
    , latest_date
  WHERE
      l.data_date = latest_date.data_date
) AS t_last_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  WITH earliest_date AS
  (
    SELECT
        ed.data_date
    FROM
        trc_warehouse_product AS ed
    WHERE
        ed.data_date >= 3
    ORDER BY
        ed.data_date ASC
    LIMIT
        1
  )
  SELECT
      f.data_date                 AS f_date
    , f.product_id                AS f_id
    , f.cumulative_product_hits   AS f_hits
    , f.cumulative_product_sales  AS f_sales
    , f.date_last_seen            AS f_last_seen
  FROM
      trc_warehouse_product AS f
    , earliest_date
  WHERE
      f.data_date = earliest_date.data_date
) AS t_first_date
  ON t_last_date.l_id = t_first_date.f_id
```

Comment: Q1: what data?   Q2: do a search on SO and you will find the answer.     Q3: enter the data in your INSERT statement

Comment: Q1 -Sample data is shown in the 'Sample Data For Testing Only' section. Q2 I have currently hardcoded the start date of 3 into my test query. Rather than this hardcoded value, can I enter the value (3 in this case) into a WHERE clause on the outer query, so an non-expert user can modify the query to get the results for different periods. Q3 The trc_warehouse_product table is automatically populated from another data source. I may not be able to add the missing data. IT may not be a problem in the long run/ Thans.

Comment: Q1: There is a better way. But it is not clear what your desired output should look like, and why the most simple query for this data (`SELECT data_date, product_id, cumulative_product_hits,, cumulative_product_sales, date_last_seen, date_product FROM trc_warehouse_product;`) is not OK.  I will not start guessing what your desired output is looking like...

Comment: Q2: -1   Q3: unclear what data should be in there, so it is impossible to add the data.

Comment: Please stop asking three questions in 1 Question. ( The button is named 'Ask question', not 'Ask questions')

Comment: Have a look at `LAG`

Comment: Sorry for asking 3 questions in one.
Regarding Q1 only.What I am trying to get is the number of sales for all products between two dates, but not the total sales for a product (which is the data in the table).
From the example data, the first date is 3 (restriction is ed.data_date >= 3) which exists as a data point. The last date is 15 (restriction is ld.data_date <= 15). This data does not exist, so we look for the first date eariler that specifid (in this case 13), So the results I want are the number of sales per product on date 13 - the number of sales per product on date 3.

Comment: I will have another look at the LAG function. My initial reading did not make too much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand your question, simple aggregation can do what you ask for:

```
select product_id,
    min(data_date) start_date, max(data_date) end_date, 
    max(data_date) - min(data_date) num_days,
    max(cumulative_product_hits) - min(cumulative_product_hits) num_hits,
    max(cumulative_product_sales) - min(cumulative_product_sales) num_sales,
    max(date_last_seen) last_seen_on
from trc_warehouse_product
where data_date >= 3 and data_date <= 15
group by product_id
```

For your sample data, [this produces](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=b8892949fe9f0fe8c1ade169b0950706):

```
product_id | start_date | end_date | num_days | num_hits | num_sales | last_seen_on
---------: | ---------: | -------: | -------: | -------: | --------: | -----------:
         1 |          3 |       13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5
         2 |          3 |        8 |        5 |        2 |         2 |            4
         3 |          3 |       13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5
         4 |          3 |       13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5
         5 |          3 |       13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5
         6 |          3 |       13 |       10 |        3 |         3 |            5
         7 |          5 |       13 |        8 |        2 |         2 |            5
```